# Different Server for Images

Tags: hosting

I am on a shared hosting on HostGator and now I want to take one other shared hosting on some server and want to put only the images used on my site to it. So that those http requests of images could go to another server, is that possible? and how? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "CDN" or "Content Delivery Network".

Here is a [WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)! definition if you are not familiar.

There are plenty of good tutorials out there that will show you how to carry this out using Wordpress.

Here is one you can have a look at.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/wordpress-cdn-content-delivery-network-configuration.html

Comment: I know about CDN and in fact am uding MaxCDN. But I literally want to keep my images onto some other server then my main server.

Comment: That is the point of a CDN.

Comment: it doesn't matter what server you keep it on as you can configure your CDN use as many servers as you want. As Joseph said that is what CDN does you just have to point to to whaterver server you want to use